# JSON Marshaller specify the attributes to display

Tags: json, grails, groovy, bootstrapping

I have a class Subscriber (parent) and Optionsdetail (child). They have one to many relationship.

class Subscriber {

```
String picture
String versionn
String title
String subtitle
Integer guid
Integer saleprice
Integer msrp
Integer costprice
String saletype
String category
String storecategory
String brand
String condition
String shipwithin
String modelskucode
String state
String link
String image
String image2
String image3
String image4
String description
String publishdate
Integer active
Integer weight
Integer quantity
String shippingprice
String whopay
String shiptolocation
String shippingmethod
String paymentmethod
String gsttype
String optionsstatus
Options options
Optionsdetails optionsdetails
```

While below is class Optiondetails

```
class Optionsdetails {
String sku
String usersku
Integer price
Integer saleprice
Integer msrp
Integer costprice
Integer quantity
Integer warningqty
String image1
Integer status
static belongTo = [subscriber: Subscriber]
```

I want to render only specific attribute from these classes, so I did code at Bootstrap as below

```
class BootStrap {
def init = { servletContext ->
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Subscriber) {
        def returnArray = [:]

        returnArray['title'] = it.title
        returnArray['Id'] = it.guid
        returnArray['description'] = it.description
        returnArray['saletype'] = it.saletype
        returnArray['options'] = ["optionName1": it.options.optionName1, "optionDetail1": it.options.optionDetail1]
        returnArray['optionsdetails'] = it.optionsdetails.list()
        return returnArray
    }

}
```

It was fine for class Subscriber attributes but how can I customize on what to view for attributes from class Optionsdetails. Like for example I don't want to display its ID and I want to arrange the attributes displayed. Below is how the JSON looks

```
    [
{
"title": "Female bag 2017 spring and summer new ladies shoulder bag wild shell small bag handbag female bag Messenger bag",
"Id": 710,
"description": "<font style=\"vertical-align: inherit;\"><font style=\"vertical-align: inherit;\">loading description...</font></font>",
"saletype": "B",
"options": {
"optionName1": "Color",
"optionDetail1": "Navy blue,light Grey,Taro purple,Deep purple,Dark gray,Pink,Light blue,Dark pink,black,Red wine,"
},
"optionsdetails": [
{
"id": 1,
"costprice": null,
"image1": "710.0",
"msrp": null,
"price": null,
"quantity": 4561,
"saleprice": null,
"sku": "Navy blue",
"status": 1,
"usersku": null,
"warningqty": 0
},
{
"id": 2,
"costprice": null,
"image1": "710.0",
"msrp": null,
"price": null,
"quantity": 4331,
"saleprice": null,
"sku": "light Grey",
"status": 1,
"usersku": null,
"warningqty": 0
},
```

Please kindly guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out that I need to create a separate registerObjectMarshaller for Optionsdetails like below to customize the attributes.
That fix the problem.

```
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Optionsdetails) {
        def returnArray = [:]

        returnArray['sku'] = it.sku
        returnArray['usersku'] = it.usersku
        returnArray['price'] = it.price
        returnArray['saleprice'] = it.saleprice
        return returnArray
    }
```